# Determine the size of caption windows 7 using java AWT

Tags: java, awt

Is their a way to determine the size of window caption using Java AWT.
I just changed the caption size on my local windows 7 machine using (Start-> Control Panel 
-> Display ->Personalization -> Window color -> Advanced appearance settings.
In the drop down select caption size and set it to 50.

Any inputs on determining the caption size using Java AWT would be greatly helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/1.4/w2k_props.html) you can find a list of properties of Windows GUI and how to retrieve them. I hope you can find the appropriate property in this list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Had just got this link and was about to post the answer!

Comment: I am wondering if AWT has a platform independent API to determine the caption size which works for Mac OS, windows and Linux. Any insight into this would greatly help!

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code to do this is as follows:

```
Integer i = (Integer) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty   
("win.frame.captionHeight");
System.out.println(i.intValue());
```