# Determine the size of caption using java AWT

Tags: java, awt

I am wondering if there is a platform independent way of finding the height of caption of Desktop.
As per post [Determine the size of caption windows 7 using java AWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148683/determine-the-size-of-caption-windows-7-using-java-awt) their exists a platform dependent way for windows. Is there any generic API that can be used to fetch the caption height (which works for MAC, windows, Linux etc).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `JFame.getInsets()` method.

It's not entirely accurate (as it gives the height of the entire title bar, not the caption height), requires the frame to be visible, but is probably the closest you are going to get without requiring a `JNI` solution.

For example, on Windows, `getInsets` gave me a `top` of 30, but `win.frame.captionHeight` gave me 21

You can have a look at further discussions on the top [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222940/how-do-you-get-the-height-of-the-titlebar-using-java-swing)

Comment: Actually I am working on an open source RDP applet code. I need to set Frame size of depending upon the caption size of the local machine. The open source code has a class which extends class Frame. So basically I need to get the caption size and then depending upon that set the frame width and height. Inside the constructor of class that extends a frame if I do a this.getInsets() it would give me a 0 since the frame height and width have not been set yet. So I am not able to use the getInsets() method. Any suggestions, if I can use any other solution to implement this,would be greatly helpful

Comment: `getInsets` is a method of `Container` which `Frame` extends from which `JFrame` extends from.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah getInsets is a method of Container. But when I call it on my frame it returns 0 because I have not yet set the frame size. The use case is to set the Frame size depending on caption size. So I may not be able to use the getInsets method to get the caption size.

Comment: @Gaurang this is a little sneaky, but you could create an off screen frame and use that to obtain the insets, but that's sneaky ;)

Comment: Actually my use case would not allow me to show another window. I think the getInsets() method returns valid values only when show() or pack() would be called which would cause the window to be visible.

Comment: @Gaurang fair enough (I did mention some of those limitations) ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you valuable inputs :)

Comment: @Gaurang sorry I couldn't help you further :(

Comment: I think your inputs helped me a lot to work around. I have posted my work around as an answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As a work around to this use case, I implemented the following steps:

1. Create a frame of size 800 x 600 and then
2. Use the getInsets() method to get the caption height and then re-size the frame.